# Countrows on dynamic column in PowerBI based on actual month

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I have a dataset structure like this:

| id | april | may | june | july |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | scheduled | done | null | done |
| 2 | scheduled | scheduled | done |  |
| 3 | ongoing | canceled | scheduled |  |
| 4 | ongoing | scheduled | scheduled |  |

I would to calculate rows where the column of actual month (june for now) is scheduled: 2!

I have tried this DAX function:

```
measure_countrows = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(df), df[**ACTUAL_MONTH(june)**] == "scheduled")
```

Answer (score 0):

First unpivot all columns except id column

[image]

Then write a measure

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Data), Data[Attribute] = LOWER(FORMAT(TODAY(), "mmmm")), Data[Value] = "scheduled")
```

[image]

Comment: if you issue resolved accept the answer and upvote